# How can i know what field of firebase was changed (using listener)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the follow listener on my application:

```
firebase.database().ref("salas/" + id).on("value", snapshot => {
   do something...
})
```

and the follow structure on firebase:

[image: Firebase structure image]

So, i need to know what field was changed. If any field or node of this structure is changed, the .on() method is called and i can get the all updated node, but, i need to do what node or key was changed,  what was the trigger for the call of method .on(), example, if was key "tela" or node "acomp_jogo". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes on the **direct** children, you can use the `child_changed` event, instead of the `value` one, as follows:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("salas/" + id)
    .on('child_changed', snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.key);
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
```

---

If you know **upfront** the exact data structure under `"salas/" + id` and this data structure has a **limited** number of children of children (of children...), you could use this technique and declare several listeners: one for the parent node and one for each child node (and potentially for each child of a child node...) as follows:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("salas/" + id)
    .on("child_changed", snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {   //If the snapshot has some children, we don't do anything, since this case will be taken into account by the listener declared for the child node
        handleChildChange(snapshot.key);
      }
    });

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("salas/" + id + "/letras")
    .on('child_changed', snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        handleChildChange("letras/" + snapshot.key);
      }          
    });

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("salas/" + id + "/temas")
    .on('child_changed', snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        handleChildChange("temas/" + snapshot.key);
      } 
    });

   //....

   handleChildChange(nodeKey) {
      //Do something with nodeKey
   }
```

Of course, this approach is only valid if the number of listeners to declare stays reasonable!

---

You will find more info on the different possible events in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html?authuser=2#on).

Comment: However, this will still not tell you which specific child value changed, just that a child node changed *somehow*, potentially deep inside the snapshot.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well, in the case of a **direct** child it does IMO, since you can get the child's key through `snapshot.key`. In case of child of a child, a diff on the child objects (before and after) would indeed be necessary.

Comment: The example provided gives children that are potentially more deep than the immediate child listener, so in this specific case, it's absolutely required in order to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any listeners set on a parent node, the callback you get from a listener will not tell you **exactly** which child node changed when you receive a new snapshot from that callback.  You will have to compare each of the child values (aka "diff" them) to figure out which one changed between the prior and new version of the snapshot.

If you attach a listener to a *specific* child node, and that node contains only one value, then that listener essentially will tell you if that value changed - it could have been newly added, changed, or removed.